# FluentNHibernate and persistence of tree structure

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have an application storing a tree structure and is able to generate the database fine, but when inserting I get an exception. I simplified the code to narrow down the problem.

The class to be saved:

```
public class Node
{
    public virtual int NodeId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Node Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Node> Children { get; set; }
}
```

This is the mapper code:

```
public sealed class NodeMap : ClassMap<Node>
{
    public NodeMap()
    {
        Id(n => n.NodeId).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(n => n.Name);
        References(n => n.Parent).LazyLoad().Nullable();
        HasMany(n => n.Children).LazyLoad().KeyColumn("ParentId");
    }
}
```

When I do an insert like `dataClient.Insert(new Node { Name = "Test" });` I get an exception saying:

> NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: could not insert: [Model.Node][SQL: INSERT INTO [Node] (Name, NodeId) VALUES (?, ?); select SCOPE_IDENTITY()]

And the inner exception says:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Node' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Which is actually perfectly understandable, but I just wonder why it is trying to set an explicit value for NodeId. When I remove the References part, the insert goes through, so it must be related to that somehow.

The version of FluentNHibernate is 1.2.0.712 and the version of NHibernate is 3.1.0.4000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is because the default column is `typename + id` for the reference which happens to be the same name as the id column. Explicitly state it in the reference.

```
References(n => n.Parent, "ParentId").LazyLoad().Nullable();
```

Update: as convention

```
public class ReferenceColumnConvention : IReferenceConvention
{
    public void Apply(IManyToOneInstance instance)
    {
        // uncomment if needed
        //if (instance.EntityType == instance.Property.PropertyType)
        instance.Column(instance.Name + "id");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Firo. That fixed the problem, and it actually makes sense.

Comment: Would it by the way be possible to make a convention handling this: If the type of the property is the same as the hosting type, then it should fall back to propertyname + id? That would be useful in most cases I think.